# How to create ForEach loop to go through multiple variables Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

I've got a problem with ForEach loop. Im trying to loop through multiple variables of same kind just increment different. 
Im trying to change the TextBox Text depending on if Label from same row has text.

This is how I could make it to just write and IF sentence for each Label but I was looking a way to loop each of these blocks through ForEach loop. I've got total of 8 Labels and Textboxes.

Here is the code: ( Im sure you'll figure out what I'm after :) )

```
IF ( $Label1.Text.Length -ne 0 ) 
{ 
    $Label1.Visible = $true
    $TextBox1.Visible = $true

    $TextBox1.Text = ( "Enter new name for " + $Label1.Text ) 
}
```

example of ForEach

```
$Count = 1..8

$Count | ForEach-Object {

     IF ( $Label($_).Text.Length -ne 0 )
     {
          $Label($_).Visible = $true
          $TextBox($_).Visible = $true

          $TextBox($_).Text = ( "Enter new name for " + $Label($_).Text )
     }
}
```

etc...

I tried putting variables in array and loop through that way but ofcourse array changes the type to string and it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, I can't test it using label & textbox object but it can work tuning it better:

```
 1..8  | ForEach-Object {

     IF ( (iex "`$Label$_.Text.Length") -ne 0 )
     {
        iex  "`$Label$_.Visible = `$true"
        iex  "`$TextBox$_.Visible = `$true"

        iex  "`$TextBox$_.Text = 'Enter new name for ' + `$Label$_.Text"
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have no idea what this is doing but trying to figure it out!

Comment: @user2656503 `iex` is the `alias` for `invoke-expression` ( try `get-help invoke-expression -full` to read about it ). Remember to accept this as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Get-Variable cmdlet for that purpose:

```
 1..8 | ForEach-Object {

     if ( (Get-Variable "Label$_").Value.Text.Length -ne 0 )
     {
         (Get-Variable "Label$_").Value.Visible = $true
         (Get-Variable "Label$_").Value.Visible = $true
         (Get-Variable "Label$_").Value.Text = ( "Enter new name for " + (Get-Variable "Label$_").Value.Text )
     }
}
```